# Start process without blocking execution?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Python script that sends data via stdout and I'm trying to get it into Unity. Unfortunately, whenever I call Process.Start() the editor freezes up even if I do it in a different thread. Here's my code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Threading;
public class stdio_test : MonoBehaviour
{
    int cycle = 0;
    System.Diagnostics.Process motion;

    void Start ( )
    {
        try
        {
            motion = new System.Diagnostics.Process ( );
            motion.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            motion.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            motion.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            motion.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            motion.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
            string path = "C:\\Users\\gummi\\Desktop\\hallow3\\motion\\demo\\motion.bat";
            motion.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c" + path;

            Thread t = new Thread(() => motion.Start());
            t.Start ( );

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            print ( e );
        }
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        //execute 2x per second (every 30 frames)
        if ( cycle % 30 == 0 )
        {
            cycle = 0;
            string data = motion.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            if ( data != null )
            {
                Debug.Log ( data );
            }
        }
        cycle++;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can start the process without Unity freezing and read the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you could make to your code to make the process clearer. I tend to keep the `Start` method for pure intialisation, and separate any processing into other methods. In this case, we set up starting the process as a `Func<bool>` and start that in the async `Process()` method. The code below also performs the reading of the output asynchronously so as not to block the editor.

```cs
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private System.Diagnostics.Process _motion;
    private Func<bool> _function;

    void Start()
    {
        _motion = new System.Diagnostics.Process ( );
        _motion.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        _motion.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        _motion.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        _motion.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        _motion.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
        string path = "C:\\Users\\gummi\\Desktop\\hallow3\\motion\\demo\\motion.bat";
        _motion.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c \"{path}\"";

        _function = new Func<bool>(() => _motion.Start());

        Process ( );
    }

    private async void Process ( )
    {
        bool started = await Task.Run(_function);
        Debug.Log ( $"Process started : {started}" );

        string? output;
        do
        {
            output = await _motion.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync ( );
            if ( output != null )
            {
                // Do your work.
                Debug.Log ( output );

                // Wait half a second.
                await Task.Delay ( 500 );
            }
        } while ( output != null );
    }
}
```

---

In addition to the above code that solves your initial problem and will allow your batch file to run, have you considered the "Python for Unity" package if you're making extensive use of Python?

[image: Package Manager highlighting Python For Unity]